# How to display utf8_general_ci encoded data into json?

Tags: php, mysql, json, encoding

I am using collection `utf8_general_ci` for my field **lang_name** which will store translated data in any language. When I fetch data from database and encode it in json, the output is something like this `"lang_name":"\u0905\u0902\u0917\u094d\u0930\u0947\u091c\u093c\u0940"` while its value in database is **अंग्रेज़ी**.

How can I get the actual value as it is stored in json format from database?

Comment: That's the expected result after JSON encoding a string with UTF-8 characters. I'm not sure I understand what the question/problem is? If you want it decoded, use `json_decode()`

Comment: As Pekka says, perfectly valid output. Any application that actually supports json would know what to do with it.

Comment: Looks like someone has to read how JSON works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `\uxxxx` in your JSON string, since it is JSON's own way of encoding special characters, e.g. UTF-8.

The string will be allright again when you use the correct JSON decoding method.

As of PHP 5.4.0 you are able to actually output the specials charaters to the JSON string, when encoded, so the browser can display the special characters when supporting e.g. UTF-8.

Use:

> `$json = json_encode($my_utf8_meshup, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

The JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE flag ensures that characters are converted into their equivalent UTF8-encoded character.

There is probably no way you can do this using any cool combination of `inconv()` parameters or `mb_convert_encoding()` since your json_encode() (before PHP 5.4.0) will eventually end up mapping it to the `\uxxxx` character conversion. Again, which is good for JSON (transportation), but maybe not be human-readable.